# Hi everyone, I'm trying to code this formula in prolog, any help is appreciated :)

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to code this formula in prolog :

"str" is input number as a string
"base" is the base of the input number.

Result is,

(base)^0 * str[len-1] + (base)^1 * str[len-2] + (base)^2 * str[len-3] + ...

I'm new to prolog and I have this right now:

```
calc([],_,0):-  !.
calc([H|T],Base,Res):-
    length([H|T],Long),
    Long >= 0,
    Size is Long - 1,
    power(Base , Size, Res),
    Res1 is Res * H,
    calc(T,Base,Res1).
```

but it doesn't work properly I spent yesterday trying to solve the problem but with no success.

Any help is appreciated :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
value(String, Base, Value) :-
    string_chars(String, Digits),
    value(Digits, Base, 0, Value).

value([], _, Value, Value).
value([Digit|Digits], Base, Accumulator, Value) :-
     atoi(Digit, Number),
     NewAccumulator is Base*Accumulator + Number,
     value(Digits, Base, NewAccumulator, Value).

atoi(Char, Int) :-  % convert ASCII code to integer
    char_code(Char, Code) ,
    Int is Code - 48.
```

The predefined predicate [`string_chars`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=string_chars/2) converts a string into a list of chars:

```
?- string_chars("1101", Chars).
Chars = ['1', '1', '0', '1'].
```

The predicate `atoi` converts a character representing a digit into a corresponding integer:

```
?- atoi('3', Integer).
Integer = 3.
```

Supposing that `[1,1,0,1]` is a list of integers (representing a number in base **2**), its corresponding value in base **10** can be computed as following:

```
Digit Accumulator
-     0
1     2 x 0 + 1 = 1
1     2 x 1 + 1 = 3
0     2 x 3 + 0 = 6
1     2 x 6 + 1 = 13
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- value("1101", 2, V).
V = 13.

?- value("1201", 3, V).
V = 46.
```

**Alternative solution** Suppossing that you already have a list of integers representing the digits of a number, the solution is even simpler:

```
value_integers(Digits, Base, Value) :-
    value_integers(Digits, Base, 0, Value).

value_integers([], _, Value, Value).
value_integers([Digit|Digits], Base, Accumulator, Value) :-
     NewAccumulator is Base*Accumulator + Digit,
     value_integers(Digits, Base, NewAccumulator, Value).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- value_integers([1,1,0,1], 2, Value).
Value = 13.

?- value_integers([1,2,0,1], 3, Value).
Value = 46.

?- value_integers([1,2,0,1], 10, Value).
Value = 1201.
```

Comment: Wow, that's actually really interesting, I learned a lot reading your response thank you. In my case, I need to convert a list of numbers into one number your explanation shows how to do so with strings if you have the time I would be very thankful if you explain to me how I can convert a list [1,2,3] to a number 123 I searched for an answer but I didn't find a simple one. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: @roeone See the alternative solution in my answer.